# Удаление (скрытие для пользователя) кнопки после ее нажатия discord.py

Tags: discord.py

```
class RequestRoleView(View):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs, timeout=None)
    @discord.ui.button(label="Ввести ник", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="enter_nickname_for_rank")
    async def enter_nick_for_rank_button(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        try:
            await interaction.response.send_modal(NicknameForRoleModal())
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Произошла ошибка: {e}")
```

Перепробовал много способов скрытия кнопки после нажатия и ничего не помогает, либо просто не работает

Comment: попробуйте `await interaction.edit_message(view=None)`

Comment: Кнопка не пропадает и вот такая ошибка 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'edit_message'

Comment: Ну, тогда не `edit_message`, а `edit_original_response`. [Документацию](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=interaction#discord.Interaction) посмотрите просто